# How can i get partial data which is in a range of date(which is also index) in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, i need to get all the `SPREAD` values which are between two dates (Eg. between 2021-03-25 and 2021-03-29)

```
DATE                          SPREAD
2021-03-23 01:16:20.510064    -35.79
2021-03-23 01:16:20.948753    -33.82
2021-03-23 01:16:21.385717    -33.82
2021-03-23 01:16:21.818057    -33.82
2021-03-23 01:16:22.249897    -33.82
                               ...  
2021-04-06 15:46:39.193054   -117.73
2021-04-06 15:46:39.447869   -117.73
2021-04-06 15:46:39.701930   -117.73
2021-04-06 15:46:39.963806   -117.73
2021-04-06 15:46:40.212487   -117.73
```

This is the code I'm trying, of course it doesn't work; it simply gives an empty dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r'filev2server.csv',index_col="DATE", parse_dates=True, delimiter=",")
filter = (data.index > start_date) & (data.index <= end_date)
data=data.loc[filter]
```

This is what i expect as an outcome (from March 25 to March 29):

```
DATE                          SPREAD
2021-03-25 00:00:00.209803    -15.18
2021-03-25 00:00:01.834820    -15.25
2021-03-25 00:00:02.269944    -14.25
2021-03-25 00:00:02.706196    -14.12
2021-03-25 00:00:03.140489    -14.55
                               ...  
2021-03-29 23:59:58.876018    -77.52
2021-03-29 23:59:59.110395    -77.52
2021-03-29 23:59:59.497492    -77.47
2021-03-29 23:59:59.727999    -76.85
2021-03-29 23:59:59.963468    -76.84
```

Comment: provide a small sample data, provide the expected output, and share the code you tried, including where you got stuck

Comment: How did you define `start_date` and `end_date` in your code?

Comment: Guess how i defined them?
`start_date = '25/03/2021'`
`end_date = '03/04/2021'`
Not the same format :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the index [**`to_datetime()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then use boolean indexing:

```py
start_date = '2021-03-25'
end_date = '2021-03-29'

data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index)
data = data[(data.index > start_date) & (data.index <= end_date)]
```